# TimeZone offset bug – Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, timezone-offset

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(-4).parse("2012-08-20T14:00:00-0400")
```

returns

> Mon, 20 Aug 2012 15:00:00 ADT -03:00

I would expect parse() to return a Time with -04:00, like Mon, 20 Aug 2012 14:00:00 EDT -04:00

How would you handle this? I think that Daylight Saving Time is messing up things here.

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this problem using new_offset from DateTime.

> time = "2012-08-20T14:00:00-0400"
>
> DateTime.parse(time).new_offset("+2")

returns Mon, 20 Aug 2012 20:00:00 +0200